# VSCode extension kick function when just open file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to open `pubspec.yaml` file and kick some function
VSCode extenision.
but nothing happned.
Why can't I?

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:yml"
],
"main": "./dist/extension.js",
"contributes": {
    "views": {
        "explorer": [
          {
            "id": "mrgao_luckys",
            "name": "pubspec.yaml"
          }
        ]
    },
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "flutter-pub-version-checker.helloWorld",
            "title": "Hello World"
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:yml"
],
```

> This activation event is emitted and interested extensions will be
> activated whenever a file that resolves to a certain language gets
> opened.  [from [onLanguage](http://from%20https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onLanguage) api]

So when you open a `yml` file the **extension** is activated, not any particular command.  The rest of your `package.json` really has nothing to do with this `onLanguage:yml`  activation.

You can see this if you simply have this in your `extension.js`:

```js
async function activate(context) {

  someFunction();   // this function will be run whenever you switch to a `yml` file.

  // this will be run too, but it just registers the command, does not trigger it
  // the command is triggered in other ways
  vscode.commands.registerCommand('flutter-pub-version-checker.helloWorld'.....{} )
}
```

Your command `flutter-pub-version-checker.helloWorld` is not activated by the language switch - it is activated through the command palette or a keybinding or a menu item selection.